# Prevent/Remove click-event on li-elements in roundabout

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm playing around with the `jQuery` roundabout and like it a lot.

However I'm wondering if anyone knows how to remove/prevent the `click` event on the `li` elements so that it will only move when a button is clicked?

I couldn't find anything on this in `roundabouts` API and couldn't find a similar question online.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('#carousel1').roundabout({clickToFocus: false});`

:)